# Extends hierarchy about private members in parent class

Tags: java, class, extends

There are two class below:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    public Animal(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat(String name) {
         super(name);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Cat cat = new Cat("Tom");
         System.out.println(cat.getName());
    }
}
```

The result is "Tom".

But the value is the property value of Animal or Cat? If is Animal, why cat can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `name` although declared `private` in `Animal` **is still inherited** in `Cat`. But, we don't have direct access to it i.e. you can't use `name` with the `.` operator like `cat.name = "Jerry"`. But, since the method `getName` is declared in `Animal` and thus has access to the private members of `Animal`. Also `getName` is `public`, so we can access it in `Cat`.

This means that we are accessing the `private` members of a super-class in a sub-class. This is pretty obvious. You may seem confused about it because many

How the `name` is set to `Tom`: - The `name` is set through the public constructor of `Animal`. And the constructor of `Cat` passes the value of `name` to the `Animal` constructor, which then sets it.

**EDIT**: When you say `Cat cat = new Cat("Tom");`, it means you have created only one object. An object of `Cat`. You haven't created an object of `Animal`. Although the constructor of `Animal` is called, it doesn't creates an instance of `Animal`. Int the above case, the property `name` belongs to the instance of `Cat` and not `Animal`.

Comment: Rahul Bobhate, the value "Tom" is belong to instance of Cat or Animal?I'm confused of where "Tom" stayed? The instance of Animal? Cat?

Answer (score 0):

`Animal` has a private member `name`; as the constructor of `Cat` calls the constructor of `Animal` which stores the name, `getName` of `Animal` can return it.